# React Native Expo: TypeError: undefined is not a function with createUserWithEmailAndPassword and Hermes JS Engine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I am developing a React Native application using Expo and Firebase. I'm trying to use the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function to create a new user with email and password authentication. However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: Hermes
```

This error seems to be related to the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function. I have been searching through the Expo and Firebase documentation, but I haven't found a suitable solution yet. Here is the code I am using:

firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey:,
  authDomain: ,
  projectId: ,
  storageBucket: ,
  messagingSenderId: ,
  appId: ,
  measurementId:,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export default { auth };
```

SignUp.js:

```
import auth from "../firebase/firebase";

function createUser() {
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
    console.log("worked");
  });
}
```

Is there a compatibility issue between the Hermes JavaScript engine and the Firebase Web SDK? Or is there any other solution to this issue?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
const app = getYourFirebaseApp()
const auth = getAuth(app);
const result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
```

this is its type

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth: Auth, email: string, password: string): Promise<UserCredential>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my firebase.js file, I changed the export statement to use named exports for the app and auth objects:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export { app, auth }; // Update this line to use named exports
```

By using named exports and correctly importing the auth object, I was able to resolve the "TypeError: of undefined" error and successfully create a new user using Firebase authentication.